# Having Trouble with SQL wanting to add temporary column

Tags: sql

I am having a hard time figuring out this SQL statement. I want to list all cities, their population and the country where the city belongs. the thing is that there are 2 tables that are needed to be used. both tables have columns that are labeled the same, i.e. country (Table) name (Column) and city (Table) name (Column)

```
SELECT 
   Name, Population, Country.name AS Country
FROM 
   City, Country.name AS Country
WHERE 
   Country.Name = (SELECT Name FROM Country);
```

I am getting this error

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'country.name' doesn't exist

Now I do not know if this is the right path to get my answer I am however just starting to use this tool and I am also reading this book MODERN DATABASE MANAGEMENT Eleventh Edition maybe I just don't understand this part yet.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the table schemas? Also, which DBMS is this?

Comment: `Country.Name = (SELECT Name FROM Country)` does not make any sense (you are essentially comparing the column to itself) Plus: in the FROM part you can only use tables, not columns. And I highly doubt that `country.name` contains the same values as `city.name` (unless you are storing countries that are cities at the same time)

Answer (score 1):

Use aliases and joins, it will make the query easier to read and understand.
You will need a relationship between your City table and Country table to make things work:

```
SELECT
 ci.Name as City, ci.Population, co.Name as Country
FROM
 City ci
 INNER JOIN Country co ON co.Id = ci.CountryId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a table named `Country.name` then this line is incorrect

```
FROM City, Country.name AS Country
```

Simply because you should be SELECTING a column named name from a table Country.

The right syntax using WHERE clause to connect two tables would be:

```
SELECT City.Name, City.Population, Country.name AS Country
FROM City, Country
WHERE Country.Name = City.CountryName
```

Assuming you have a field `CountryName` in table `City` since your line

```
WHERE Country.Name = (SELECT Name FROM Country);
```

Is wrong, because you are trying to connect field `Name` from `Country` with the same field.